# Lottie animation on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using this animation in my react native Expo app:
https://www.lottiefiles.com/86-bouncy-dribbble-ball

The animation runs, I can see the shadow of the ball but I can't see the ball image.

The image is defined like this in the animation json file:

`[{"id":"image_0","w":289,"h":287,"u":"images/","p":"img_0.png"}]`

I put the image and the json file into the same folder. I guess Lottie can't find the image. I tried lots of different combinations for the **"u"** parameter but I couldn't manage to show the image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This happened to me but I wasn't using Expo. Try wrapping the animation inside a <View> component

Comment: @ChiamakaNwolisa Thank you. It's already in a View component.

Comment: Did you ever find solution for this?

Comment: @skyguy Unfortunately, no.

Comment: so you never got images to work in your animations? what did you end up doing?

Comment: @skyguy I am going to look at it again at a later time. I'm using React Animated as a temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks, can you port Aftereffects animations to React Animated do you know?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/issues/145

I found the solution - just drag the images folder into your bundle resources in your Xcode project.